# Azure Notification Hubs - How to get total count of active device registered

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We are using [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/4.0.0) to create registration and send push requests. We are almost reached limit in 10 million devices and looking to the way to destribute our devices between 2, 3 hubs.

We need to get "Active Device Registered" value, I found that we can use azure.managment rest api with notification hub provider to get it. We also can try to "Read all registrations" with checking ContinuationToken to get registrations batches and calculate this value on our side.

So, do we have other options to get "Active Device Registered" value?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Active device registered can be seen in Overview blade from Azure Portal,

You may want to know that **Active devices** are devices eligible to receive notifications. They are defined as **unique registration IDs** for devices using Google Cloud Messaging or Amazon Device Messaging, channel uniform resource identifiers (URI) for devices using Windows notification service or Microsoft push notification Service, or device tokens for devices using Apple push notification service.

And when active device quota is reached, All new registrations against any hubs within the namespace of whose active device quota is reached will be interrupted.

In order to add more active devices you would need to create another notification namespace if the current limit hits the maximum value as per the quota limit that is limited to namespace level.

If you need support for more than 10 million registered devices, you must partition your devices across multiple namespaces.

Reference: [What is resource structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq#what-is-the-resource-structure-of-notification-hubs-);  [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq#how-many-devices-can-i-support-if-i-send-push-notifications-via-notification-hubs-),

See: [Notification Hubs Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/)

Also If you do not want to increase to another pricing tear or create new namespaces when the current one reaches the maximum number, you may delete registrations.

Installations are not automatically removed from our end unless they expire. The expiration is set at the hub level and will default to never expire; overriding this will give an expiration time to each device registered from the hub.

See [expirationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-overwrite-installation#request-body) property on the request body for creation of an installation.

Comment: Thanks, I needed exactly dailyMaxActiveDevices. Yup, it presented on the azure portal, but I needed to get it from my app, to find hub with less active devices.

Answer (score 0):

So, used this api request to get dailyMaxActiveDevices for all hubs in my namespace from our .net core app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/notification-hubs/list?tabs=HTTP

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).